# PHP require_once not working for footer

Tags: php

I want to add a common code for footer on all my web pages. I created a new php file named commonFooter.php and have the below code in it:

```
<?php
   echo '--footer-code-in-html--';
?>
```

On my home page I added the below code:

```
<?php require_once('/static/v3/commonFooter.php'); ?> // /static/v3 is the path of the commonFooter.php
```

But somehow the footer is not showing up on the webpage. Can anyone help me out what am I missing.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `<?php require_once('static/v3/commonFooter.php'); ?>`? In other words, the `static` directory is relative to the file doing the requiring?

Comment: enable PHP error reporting, what does it say ?

Comment: This is issue of path. Try `'static/v3/commonFooter.php'`

Comment: Just to clarify, the path is correct as far as I know. Because that's where all my files are stored in FTP and I have been using the same paths for all my links, which are working perfectly fine. Also, I can see the footer contents if I type the url: http://example.com/static/v3/commonFooter.com

Comment: `example.com/static/v3/commonFooter.com`? But you are including `.php`, not `.com`

Comment: It was by mistake. I wanted to write commonFooter.php and not commonFooter.php

Answer (score 0):

The require_once statement is identical to require except PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.

See the include_once documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php echo('/static/v3/commonFooter.php'); ?>
```

If that works and the statement is printed out in the page , Try

```
<?php require_once('static/v3/commonFooter.php'); ?>
```

If that fails, then take a share the folder structure of your project.

Comment: Hi Fawzan, the first one works. The second, unfortunately, does not. I am sorry but I did not get the solution you said for the fail part.

Comment: are you sure you have turned on the errors/warnings on in php.ini ?

Comment: I do not have the rights to edit anything on php.ini. Is there a workaround for this? Also, there is no error message as such, because the page loads normally, except for the footer part.

Comment: add error_reporting(E_ALL); to the start of the file

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I added error_reporting(E_ALL); at the start of the file. In my url, I appended '?showerror=yes'. Still the page gets loaded, footer doesn't.

Comment: In that case. You have to share the cod if you need help.